# angular routing : resolve vs. controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I haven't find an answer on the Internet so I came here to ask for help :

**What is the best practice to use when changing a state in AngularJS ?**

The first that I found is using ui.router with the resolve method. You can then inject data to the controller.

On the other hand, following [johnpapa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) guidelines, I have found that you can also use the `activate()` method.

So, what is the best way to get data (let's say a list of users) when going on the state `/users` : use the `activate()` method to gather the list of users, or use the `resolve` in the routing to inject the list of users ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question seems to be opinion based, I would recommend using a resolve for a state when the data requested is absolutely necessary for the state to be shown. If the data fails to load the error handler will automatically route to the error state.

If you get the data in your controller you have to do the error handling/redirecting yourself and might result in flashing screens/strange behaviour because the request first has to finish/fail while to template is already loaded.

Comment: I am actually looking for this kind of answers so thank you !